# Using ${catalina.base}/logs for org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory does not work in JavaSE

Tags: java, logging, configuration

I'm using the **tomcat-juli-8.5.90.jar** and correct putting on the classpath when I run the application I set the parameter `-Djava.util.logging.config.file` that points to this configuration

```
handlers = org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = INFO
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.maxDays = 90
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.encoding = UFT-8
org.apache.juli.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level     = INFO
```

The application runs well but a new folder is created with the name ${catalina.base} in the current working directory of the application.
[file created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zd3kZ.png)

I'm running the app in a JavaSE environment. This is test code

```
package com.mycompany.loggertest;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Test {
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Test.class.getName());
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LOG.info("Hello world");
    }
}
```

I already test with others well defined system properties like java.home, but a folder ${java.home} is created. In the documentation says this:

[System property replacement is performed for property values which contain ${systemPropertyName}.](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html#Using_java.util.logging_(default))

The value with the system property will be replaced

Comment: Why do you use Tomcat Logging when you do not start a Tomcat web server? The documentation assumes that it runs within Tomcat and (without further investigating it) most likely the resource filtering replacing the variables is done by some other component of Tomcat. For JavaSE I think you are better off with a logging framework that can be used standalone, like logback or Log4J.

Comment: I started to use this Logging because two features, the maxDays property that erase any older Log file and the name that includes by default the date.

I'm guessing that, the replacing is done by other component because I did a quick reading of the source code of org.apache.juli.FileHandler  and there isn't any replacing logic.